# Role in Ansible is not loading vars subfolder

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and not very versed to Linux in general so this is probably quite basic question but it makes me scratch my head quite for some time. Debugging with several levels of verbosity, Googling for problem nor study of several tutorials didn´t provide an answer nor hint what is wrong. But to my issue:

I tryied to use roles for reusability. I manually made folders `tasks` and `roles` directly under `/etc/ansible/roles` on my DEV machine. But after decomposing original playbook into role it stared failing with error `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'groups_additional' is undefined`.

My decomposed files:

playbook test_user.yml

```
---
- hosts: test_host
  remote_user: test
  gather_facts: no

  roles:
    - user

  vars:
    user_name: test
    user_pwd: <secret>
    group_name: test_grp
```

roles/user/tasks/main.yml ############ Error happens here in `groups`

```
---
- name: Check '{{ user_name }}' user, set his pwd and groups
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: '{{ user_name }}'
    password: '{{ user_pwd }}'
    group: '{{ user_name if group_name is undefined else group_name }}'
    groups: '{{ user_name if group_name is undefined else group_name }} {{ groups_additional if groups_additional is defined }}'      
  become: yes  #use sudo
```

roles/user/vars/main.yml

```
---
groups_additional: ', qwqe'
```

Please, note that this is really simplified version of my playbook but with important places presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR**: Check owner and permissions

---

Disclaimer: This is my own question and I am answering so another unhappy person might get hint what might get wrong.

The reason is relatively simple, yet somewhat hidden.

After running playbook under `sudo` it played along without any problem. Then I noticed that `vars` folder was owned by root, but `tasks` by user `usr_ansible` (under which I was running Ansible playooks). After change of owner + group it is okay and `ansible-playbook` works even without `sudo`.

Comment: You do not need any disclaimer. It's common practice to answer own question and mark own question answered by accepting own answer.

Comment: I know I do not need disclaimer but I want to make it immediately obvious. :-) And about accepting, I want to wait a few days to allow for some another answers ideas before choosing answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly used `default.yml` instead of `main.yml`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used variables names which matched both vars/main.yml & hostvars ( inside inventory ) which caused an error while parsing the entire file.